# Generic Required Field check for lightning-input-field of Child component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a child component, in which I'm using **lightning-record-edit-form** and in that I have **lightning-input-field** where some of them are required.

Now when I'm submitting the form from parent I want to check all required field, without hardcoding them.

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="SalesRequest__c">
        <!-- Account Creation Section -->
        <div if:true={createAccount} class="slds-m-top_medium">
            
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Street__c" data-name="Street__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="City__c" data-name="City__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="State__c" data-name="State__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                    
                    
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Is_owner__c" data-name="Is_government_owner__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="ZipCode__c" data-name="ZipCode__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Country__c" data-name="Country__c" required="true"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<template>
<c-sales-request request-type={reqType}></c-sales-request>
</template>
```

**Parent Component JS:**

```
const childcomp = this.template.querySelector('c-sales-request');
        console.log('>>> childcomp... '+JSON.stringify(childcomp));
        if(childcomp != undefined){
            let childfields = childcomp.getRecordEditFormData();
            console.log('>>> childfields... '+JSON.stringify(childfields));
            if( childfields != undefined){
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(childfields)) {
                    console.log('>>> key... '+key);
                    console.log('>>> value... '+value);
                    
                    if(key == 'Is_owner__c' && value == null){ // here I'm hardcoding required value
                        this.isRquiredCheck = true;
                    }else if(key == 'Is_owner__c' && value != null){
                        this.isRquiredCheck = false;
                    }

                    fields[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

So instead of hardcoding all required field name, I want to know if there is a generic way to check if all required fields are filled or not

Answer (score 0):

`lightning-record-edit-form`  by default, check for validations & required fields by `record-type-id`, you don't need to make it specific

please have a look [lightning-documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation#:%7E:text=lightning%2Drecord%2Dedit%2Dform%20handles,blank%20and%20move%20focus%20away.)

Comment: unfortunately it's not doing validation checks